# How do i find the first un-escaped quotes in Java?

Tags: java, regex, escaping

Example, I have the folowing String:

```
    String str = "te\\\"st\""
```

and I must find the index of the first un-escaped(without \) ". 
In the example the right index is 9.

Is there any regex or any other solution to resolve this problem?

I have the following code

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(HERE A REGEX);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(json);

    if(matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.start());
    }
```

but I don't know what kind of regexp to use.

Comment: Did you mean to use `String str = "te\\\"st\""`? And it is the 7th char, not the 9th. Please share the non-working code to clarify what issue you are having.

Comment: Yes, sorry I mean String str = "te\\\"st\"".

Comment: Good, so what is the issue with your approach? Note that `Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(HERE A REGEX);` does not compile. What is the pattern you tried?

Comment: Once you come up with something please update the question, it is off-topic for the time being.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this regex to find  first un-escaped quote,

```
^[^"\\]*?(?:[\\]{2})*(")
```

[Demo](http://%5E[%5E%22%5C%5C]*?(?:[%5C%5C]%7B2%7D)*(%22)),,, in which I intended to capture the first unescaped quote to `group 1` (`\1` or `$1`).

And for finding the `index` of the `quote`( `captured group 1`), you will need to retrieve the value,

```
matcher.start(1)
```